# Sencha 1.1 picker - xtype is not being registered

Tags: extjs, picker

I am trying to add a picker to a tool Bar in Sencha using its xtype (which is, according to the sencha docs, 'picker') - but I keep getting this error from the Chrome developer tools: 
        "Uncaught Attempting to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered: picker"

This is my code:

```
{xtype: 'picker', width:160,
                slots:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'pickerslot',
                        name: 'states',
                        data: statusStore.data.items
                    }
                ],
                cancelButton: false,
                doneButton: false,
                listeners:{
                    pick : function(field, value) {
                        selectedStatus = value.states;
                    },
                    afterrender : function(picker) {
                        if (FPA.stores.DataProvider.listItemsStore) {
                            //Ext.ComponentMgr.get('statList').setValue(FPA.stores.DataProvider.listItemsStore.status);
                        } else {
                            // Ext.ComponentMgr.get('statList').setValue(statusStore.data.get(0));
                        }
                    }
                }},
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Ext.reg('picker',Ext.Picker);` above the xreate statement, and see if that fixes your problem. Sencha touch 1.1 docs are *awesome*

Comment: Yes, I've noticed on my own after that that they forgot to register the xtype. Doing it manually solved that...